# Why are norms for extensions of $\Bbb Z$ always integers in algebraic number theory?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Why are norms for extensions of $\Bbb Z$ always integers in algebraic number theory ?

Suppose we have $\Bbb Z[x]$ and $\Bbb Z[y]$.

They have norms that map them to positive integers.

Why can they not have one of them being the norm of the other ?

For instance why are there no rings with norm $\Bbb Z[i]$ the gaussian integers ?

I assume if a ring has another ring as a kind of norm then that norm must be a subring.
I can think of other obstacles but no strong reason. Unique factorization, class numbers etc.

Then again norms do not always have the nice properies, they can be non-multiplicative for instance.

So since there are not thight restrictions for norms, I do not see why other rings could not serve ?

But I never see them.

Am I wrong and poorly informed, or is there a reason ?

Maybe it relates to zero-divisors ?

Or maybe it is inherited from the determinant idea, and maybe we should be more flexible ?

***EDIT***

The following question with comments and answers was illuminating to me.

[When is the norm of a ring $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-p}]$ multiplicative?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4724828/when-is-the-norm-of-a-ring-bbb-z-sqrt-p-multiplicative)

The connection to determinants was insightful.

I will accept Paul's answer in addition to that.

Together they make things much more clear to me.

In short, I better understand the logic and power of the norms we use.
This does not completely resolve my question of why not using another norm, but It does make the current norm concepts much more logical, powerful and justified.

Unfortunately this question is closed and thus no more answers are possible.

Although I understand this question might be way too open and general.

Comment: What do you mean?  The norm from the real quadratic field $\mathbb Q[\sqrt D]$ with $D>0$ is $x^2-Dy^2$.  And are you only considering extensions of $\mathbb Q$?  If you considered, say, extensions of $\mathbb Q[i]$ you'd get different results.

Comment: Please edit your post for clarity.  As it stands, it isn't at all clear what you are asking.

Comment: If $L/K$ is an extension of number fields, then the norm $N_{L/K} : \mathcal{O}_L \to \mathcal{O}_K$ does not take integer values in general. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_norm

Comment: @lulu you are right, I was thinking about specific rings , inconsistant with the general statement in the OP. I edited.

Comment: But the edit didn't clarify anything.  If you only consider extensions over the usual integers, that's where the norm will go.  By definition.  You are, of course, free to consider extensions of other fields.

Comment: @lhf the examples at wiki are integers , not say $1 + \sqrt 17$

Comment: Try $L=\mathbb Q(i,\sqrt{17})$ and $K=\mathbb Q(\sqrt{17})$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an obvious potential confusion between two uses of the word "norm". First, there is a metrical "norm" in the sense of a real-valued, multiplicative, etc., function on a field or whatever. Second, there is *Galois* norm. The metrical norm need not take integer values, but, well, it's convenient to normalize it so that it does. The Galois norm, applied to algebraic integers, takes algebraic-integer values in whatever the fixed field is of the Galois group we have acting.

In the metric case, the point is that the possible values are a *discrete* subgroup of $\mathbb R$, as opposed to something else. Then, we can renormalize the values to be $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: but why are the gaussian integers never a norm of something ?

Comment: In a non-metrical sense, the Gaussian integers certainly can be values of _Galois_ norms from finite extensions. They'd not be _metrical_ norm values, because they're not naturally ordered, while the real numbers _are_ naturally ordered, so real values can be used for "size" comparisons. Sure, we could somehow axiomatize some sort of complex-valued "metrical" norm, but it might not be useful... (After all, distances are mostly real numbers, not something fancier...)

Comment: yeah but say the norm is a ring that is not a UFD and the norm is multiplicative then it follows the original ring was not a UFD right ? so that would be useful.

Comment: @mick, belatedly: no, it does _not_ follow that a (Galois?) norm hitting a non-UFD ring of algebraic integers implies that the "source" ring of algebraic integers is not a UFD. It's not elementary, but there are examples where an extension ring of a non-UFD is a UFD. (This goes back to Kummer/Kronecker ideas about "ideal numbers", prior to Dedekind's general ideal theory.)

Comment: yes you are right , I remember now. Sorry and thanks +1