# When is the norm of a ring $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-p}]$ multiplicative?

Tags: ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory, diophantine-equations, multiplicative-function

I got inspired by quadratic rings and zeta functions. I know for instance that the norm $a^2 + 17 b^2$ for the ring $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-17}]$ is multiplicative yet the ring $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-17}]$ is not a UFD !!

So I wonder, for an integer $n>0$ :

When is the norm of a ring $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-n}]$ multiplicative ?

And in particular when $p$ is a prime :

When is the norm of a ring $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-p}]$ multiplicative ?

Im not sure what the best way is to test it for a given $n$ or $p$ but I can imagine it is doable with basic modular arithmetic ( quadratic residue , generator , fermats little etc ) and/or testing some small cases.

But I am not (only) interested in a specific case, I wonder about the set of them.
Are there infinitely many and do they have a closed form or a good asymptotic ?
Do they have number theoretical properties apart from satisfying the above ?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta%E2%80%93Fibonacci_identity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For *every* nonsquare integer $d$ (positive or negative), the norm mapping ${\rm N} : \mathbf Z[\sqrt{d}] \to \mathbf Z$ where ${\rm N}(a+b\sqrt{d}) = a^2 - db^2$ (equivalently, ${\rm N}(\alpha) = \alpha\overline{\alpha}$, where $\overline{\alpha}$ is the conjugate of $\alpha$) is multiplicative. This has nothing at all to do with modular arithmetic or with whether or not $\mathbf Z[\sqrt{d}]$ is a UFD.

Comment: I am aware of that KCd, but here $d$ is NEGATIVE !

Comment: So what?  The sign of $d$ is irrelevant to multiplicativity of the norm.

Comment: the norm of $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$ is not multiplicative !?

Comment: The norm on $\mathbf Z[\sqrt{-5}]$, where ${\rm N}(a+b\sqrt{-5}) = a^2 + 5b^2$, is multiplicative.  That's a special case of what I wrote above. Just *check* the norm is multiplicative in the general case (for each nonsquare $d$). It's a purely algebraic calculation.  If you are unsure of this, try the special cases $d = 5$ and $d = -5$.  The general case goes through in the same way as those two cases and the sign of $d$ plays no significant role in checking multiplicativity of the norm.

Comment: you are right ! I made a mistake in my calculations and therefore make wrong conclusions

Comment: Sorry for being confused

Comment: @mick, I guess the point of the existence of this site is to help people become less confused. :)

Comment: @paulgarrett And that is exactly why I usually do not like to vote close,delete or downvote without a single comment or attempt.

Answer (score -1):

It turns out the norm is always multiplicative.

$$(a^2 + n b^2)(c^2 + n d^2) = (ac - nbd)^2 + n(ad + bc)^2 = (ac + nbd)^2 + n (ad - bc)^2 $$

The bigger picture is that norms are multiplicative because norms are special cases of determinants of matrices.

Notice a ring maps $\Bbb N^m$ to $\Bbb N^m$ hence the matrix representation must be a square.
.
And determinants of square matrices are indeed always multiplicative.

A proof of that is given here

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant

It is natural to define norms as determinants of square matrices for the same reasons as working with determinant for square matrices in linear algebra is logical.

Im talking here in the context of integral domains, not sure how to see it in more general cases but it probably is the same. Afterall a zero-divisor is a determinant zero in its matrix representation.

Comment: there is also multiplication for $a^2 + ab + n b^2$

Comment: I believe that is a norm , not ? @WillJagy

Comment: yes.......................

Comment: @WillJagy all multiplicative things defined over the integers with only one value reaching zero ( for zero ) are norms ...